# Apache Commons Email não envia e-mail utilizando Gmail

Tags: java, apache, spring, email, gmail

[Clique aqui](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email) para abrir o repositório no Maven Repository quanto ao Apache Commons Email.

Tenho o seguinte código que recebe de um formulário o destinatário, assunto e a mensagem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/email_commons/send" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"subject", "message", "to"})
public @ResponseBody Boolean enviaEmail(
        @RequestParam(value = "subject") String subject,
        @RequestParam(value = "message") String message,
        @RequestParam(value = "to") String to,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthentication("user_exemplo@gmail.com", "senha");
    email.setSSL(true);
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.setFrom("de@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setMsg(message);
    email.addTo(to);

    try {

        email.send();

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Porém quando tenta enviar a partir da linha `email.send()` retorna **false** e aparece isso no **console**:

```
10:53:05,854 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.3
10:53:05,855 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
10:53:05,855 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
10:53:05,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
10:53:05,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
10:53:05,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
10:53:05,857 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
10:53:05,962 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
10:53:05,963 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
10:53:05,963 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
10:54:06,063 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW: 
10:54:06,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
10:54:06,064 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
10:54:06,065 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
10:54:06,065 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
10:54:06,065 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
10:54:06,065 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
10:54:06,065 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
10:54:06,067 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
10:54:06,067 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
10:54:06,067 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2285)
10:54:06,067 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2032)
10:54:06,068 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
10:54:06,068 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
10:54:06,068 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
10:54:06,068 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
10:54:06,068 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
10:54:06,074 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
10:54:06,076 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
10:54:06,076 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
10:54:06,076 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at controller.EmailController.baixarContaPagar(EmailController.java:42)
10:54:06,077 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:54:06,077 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
10:54:06,077 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
10:54:06,078 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
10:54:06,078 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
10:54:06,078 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
10:54:06,078 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
10:54:06,079 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
10:54:06,079 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
10:54:06,079 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
10:54:06,079 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
10:54:06,079 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
10:54:06,080 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
10:54:06,080 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
10:54:06,080 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
10:54:06,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
10:54:06,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
10:54:06,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
10:54:06,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
10:54:06,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
10:54:06,082 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
10:54:06,082 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,082 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
10:54:06,082 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
10:54:06,082 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,083 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
10:54:06,083 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
10:54:06,083 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
10:54:06,083 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
10:54:06,083 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
10:54:06,084 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
10:54:06,084 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,084 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
10:54:06,084 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,084 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
10:54:06,085 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
10:54:06,086 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
10:54:06,086 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
10:54:06,086 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:54:06,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18) org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
10:54:06,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
10:54:06,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at controller.EmailController.baixarContaPagar(EmailController.java:42)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
10:54:06,090 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
10:54:06,091 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
10:54:06,092 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
10:54:06,093 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
10:54:06,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18) Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   nested exception is:
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2305)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2032)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
10:54:06,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   ... 46 more
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
10:54:06,096 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2285)
10:54:06,097 ERROR [stderr] (default task-18)   ... 54 more
```

O que pode ser? Já mudei as portas do SMTP para 465, 487 e 25, o HostName, mexi com as configurações de SSL, porém nada resolveu.

Comment: Quando eu utilizei o Gmail como mailer de uma aplicação java, tive que liberar o acesso nas configurações do próprio Gmail. Você já fez isso? Caso não tenha feito, sugiro o material de apoio https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=pt-BR.

Comment: Já verificou seu firewall e proxy?

Comment: Já esta habilitado nas configurações do Google quanto a isso @WeslleyTavares, fui conferir.

Comment: No PHP utilizo os mesmos parâmetros e envia normalmente @Techies.

Comment: Já tentou com outro servidor de email? Tipo um mailinator da vida?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, ficou assim:

```
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    // email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
    email.setAuthentication("user", "password");
    email.setFrom("user");
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setMsg(message);
    email.addTo(to);
```

Coloquei o TLS por último, só é estranho porque utilizando SSL não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Para que o SSL funcione seu servidor precisar ter uma autenticação SSL para que o GMAIL reconheça.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51975)

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, é uma resposta curta, pobre em referências, mas **é uma resposta** e não deve ser apagada. Pode votar negativo se quiser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the @Giancarlo's sample works.

Another way to work, also with SSL, was use config by properties:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

Properties properties = System.getProperties();
// Setup mail server
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password");

        }

    });

email.setMailSession(session); //add session to HtmlEmail
email.setFrom(de);  
email.addTo(para);
```